# Need to understand Display data using Knockout in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

i am not very familiar with Knockoutjs. so i was reading article on Knockoutjs. this is the url http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/display-data-using-knockout-in-mvc-4/ from where i was reading.

i do not understand Knockoutjs related code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function EmployeeViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        //Declare observable
        self.EmployeeID = ko.observable("");
        self.FirstName = ko.observable("");
        self.LastName = ko.observable("");
        self.City = ko.observable("");
        self.Region = ko.observable("");
        self.PostalCode = ko.observable("");
        self.Country = ko.observable("");

        var Employee = {
            EmployeeID: self.EmployeeID,
            FirstName: self.FirstName,
            LastName: self.LastName,
            City: self.City,
            Region: self.Region,
            PostalCode: self.PostalCode,
            Country: self.Country
        };

        self.Employee = ko.observable();
        self.Employees = ko.observableArray();
        // Initialize the view-model

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployees", "Employee")',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                self.Employees(data);
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var viewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
    }
</script>
```

i understand that first `EmployeeViewModel()` function is called.

i understand this way declared observable property.

### problem area 1

```
var self = this;
self.EmployeeID = ko.observable("");
self.FirstName = ko.observable("");
self.LastName = ko.observable("");
self.City = ko.observable("");
self.Region = ko.observable("");
self.PostalCode = ko.observable("");
self.Country = ko.observable("");
```

but i do not understand the below code.....just see and tell me what it is doing

### problem area 2

```
var Employee = {

            EmployeeID: self.EmployeeID,
            FirstName: self.FirstName,
            LastName: self.LastName,
            City: self.City,
            Region: self.Region,
            PostalCode: self.PostalCode,
            Country: self.Country
        };
self.Employee = ko.observable();
self.Employees = ko.observableArray();
```

just do not understand `how each Employee will be pushed to Employees arrays` ?
if possible please help me to understand full knockout js related code like what is going on. thanks

Comment: the pushing of each employee into the arry is done on ajax success : `success: function (data) {
                self.Employees(data);
            }`

Comment: your are not pushing each employee . From server you get `data` with array of say 100 employees with details & now you are just assigning array to observablearray . pushing is not required here . Cheers

Comment: anyone can explain the problem area 1 & 2. what those code was doing? if possible explain the flow of the code execution in detail of above knockout js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.Employee = ko.observable();
```

I don't see `Employee` being used anywhere in the js code. I assume it may be declared for storing the current instance being updated.

```
self.Employees = ko.observableArray();
```

But `Employees` is defined as `ObservableArray` that means Knockout will keep watching at that array and when any thing is being assigned to that array or added to that array it would also update the ui where some foreach kind of stuff would have been implemented.

for observable array and foreach binding look at **official documentation** of **knockout js** => [link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

**Update**

Employees collection has binding in the following html.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: EmployeeID">
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: FirstName">
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: LastName">
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: City">
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: Region">
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: PostalCode">
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: Country">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.edit">
                    Edit</button>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.delete">
                    Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

So after ajax success call whatever the Json will be back will get assigned to employees collection as defined in below snippet.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployees", "Employee")',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                self.Employees(data);
            }
        });
```

Now its knockout's turn to Create as many rows as there are in Employees observable array. Even if you add any object to that observable array at runtime it would have Created tr and td tags for you. You don't need to bother about that.

Comment: sorry to request you that can you please explain each line of knockout code because things is not clear to me.

Comment: @Mou I have updated my answer. Does it now make sense to you?

Comment: please see the problem 1 & 2 area and explain why those code wrote. why employee object is created? without creating i guess job can be done.

Comment: @Thomas Employee is not used anywhere I have mentioned it in answer

Comment: Employeeid,firstname etc has no relation with employees array then how data will be pushed to those property when data will be pushed to employees array?

Comment: @Thomas if you look at the `EmployeeController` => `GetAllEmployees` it returns collection of Employee controller. Which is being invoked by $.ajax function in javascript and its callback does have responsibility to get that collection of employee to the employees list in javascript thus EmployeeId, firstname (employee class properties) is related to the employees array.